# Different Distance Matrix with Different Linkage used in Hierarchical Clustering

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering

How can we get quickly result from Hierarchical clustering using different distance matrix and linkage method in R?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer, we can write custom function with which can handle this type of problem in R and with little bit change in python as well.

```
hierarchical_clust <- function(orig_data_frame,x1,x2,n)
{
 y= dist(orig_data_frame,method =x1)
 fit <- hclust(y,method=x2)
 groups <- cuttree(fit,n)
 clust_centers <- aggregate(orig_data_frame,list(groups),mean)

}
```

Comment: Replace x1 with distance you want to try. Replace x2 with linkage method and n with number of cluster you want to try